# MPG Text field isn't updating with Javascript getElementById

Tags: javascript, textbox, textfield

I'm having trouble with getting var mpg total into the "Miles Per Gallon" text field. It worked with the var $ but I am trying to get away from the shortcut. I'm not finding the answer on Stackoverflow or Google. Is anyone able to see where I went wrong?

```
<script>
    var $ = function (id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    }                           

    var calculateMpg = function () {            
        var miles = parseFloat($("miles").value); 
          var gallons = parseFloat($("gallons").value); 

        if (isNaN(miles) || isNaN(gallons)) {    
            alert("Both entries must be numeric"); 
        }
        else {                      
            var mpg = miles / gallons;       
            function (id) {
                return (document.getElementById("mpg").value).toFixed(3); 
            }
        }
    }
    window.onload = function () {       
        $("calculate").onclick = calculateMpg;  
        $("gallons").focus();         
    }
</script>

</head>

<body>
<section>
    <h1>Calculate Miles Per Gallon</h1>
    <label for="miles">Miles Driven:</label>
    <input type="text" id="miles"><br>

    <label for="gallons">Gallons of Gas Used:</label>
    <input type="text" id="gallons"><br>

    <label for="mpg">Miles Per Gallon</label>
    <input type="text" id="mpg" disabled><br>

    <label>&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="button" id="calculate" value="Calculate MPG"><br>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To just get the above code to display mpg in the textfield:

```
<script>
    var $ = function (id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    }                           

    var calculateMpg = function () {            
        var miles = parseFloat($("miles").value); 
          var gallons = parseFloat($("gallons").value); 

        if (isNaN(miles) || isNaN(gallons)) {    
            alert("Both entries must be numeric"); 
        }
        else {                      
            var mpg = miles / gallons;       
            document.getElementById("mpg").value = mpg.toFixed(3);
            //function (id) {
            //    return (document.getElementById("mpg").value).toFixed(3); 
            //}
        }
    }
    window.onload = function () {       
        $("calculate").onclick = calculateMpg;  
        $("gallons").focus();         
    }
</script>
```

In the code that's commented out: it's not possible to define an anonymous function like this. Even if it were possible, the function is not being called anywhere, so the mpg field will never be updated.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to change the value of the 'mpg' field but you're not telling it what you want the value to be: .value() will only return the current value, .value(mpg) will try to set the value. You need something like:

```
var set_mpg_field = function(mpg){
  var mpg_field = document.getElementById("mpg");
  mpg_field.value(mpg.toFixed(3));
}
```